# Does cloud-based map styling for Android MapView work on virtual devices?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've followed the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id) to the letter to get cloud-based map styling working with my Android app but the normal style loads every time.

I've linked the map ID to the map style, and I've provided the map ID in the layout resource file.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer) article, cloud-based map styling requires the new map renderer to work. In the activity, I requested the latest renderer via `MapsInitializer.initialize` but when I check the renderer in the callback it is always `LEGACY`.

Google Play Services are fully up to date on the emulated device - a Pixel 7 with Android 13.0 - and there's plenty of storage. Maps SDK for Android is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0`.

Does cloud-based map styling work with any virtual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer is Yes

Longer answer is what you have mentioned. You need the [New Map Renderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer) to make **Cloud Based Maps Styling** work.

As of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0` the default renderer is already the **New One** so no need to **opt in**.

Before `18.2`, you still need to opt in for the **New Map Renderer**. But as of writing this answer, the link to the [New Map Renderer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer) now specifies to **opt out** of the New Map renderer to continue using the **Old Map Renderer**.

So make sure that you're not using `MapsInitializer.initialize` to actually opt out of the **New Map Renderer**.

Before `18.2`, there were times where you need to wait for the `LATEST` renderer to be included in your emulator so you might need to ***wait for a while after creating a virtual new device***.

With that said, here's what you need to make sure:

- You're using a virtual device with Google Play:
  [image: Emulator]
- Make sure that you have finished the `set up your device` prompt to enable Google Play.
- You're using the `LATEST` renderer.
- as long as you follow the guide in the [Add the map ID to your app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id#add-a-map-id-to-your-app) Cloud Based Maps Styling should work fine.
- Make sure that when creating/using a Map ID, it has **`Android`** as its `type`. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id#create-a-map-id

Here's an example to prove that Cloud Based Maps Styling works fine in a Virtual Device using `Pixel 3 API 33` in Android Studio:

[image: Emulator sample]

repo used and modified: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples

Comment: Good to know it actually works. As for why it doesn't work for me, I'm not entirely sure. Everything you've said I have covered, but `LEGACY` is always the renderer. It must be as you mentioned about it being included in the emulator. I'll try a different API level/device and see what difference it makes.

Comment: Oh right! Totally forgot to mention that you must use an Emulator with Google Play.

Comment: I edited my answer to include it also.

Comment: I had actually already tried a Google Play device. I tried it again and it still didn't work. But then I noticed in the notification tray a "set up your device" prompt. I did that, restarted the app, and it worked. If you add that to the "wait for a while after creating a virtual new device" section I'll accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think the "set up your device" prompt is the one responsible for enabling the Google Play Services in your device which is required for the New Map renderer. I have edited the answer (I put it under the "need to make sure" section)

Comment: Potentially. It's just easy to miss and not entirely obvious - especially as I had already updated Play Services on the Play Store.